# Rails Views [confused by guide]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been confused by the following lines:

```
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Remove', book, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

from

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
```

what is 'edit_book_path(book)' defined? Can you possibly explain what that means? Does it look at the controller '*book*' and check the controller method 'edit' while passing in the variable book?

What is `<%= link_to 'Show', book %>`? Is it go to the controller method 'show'? Or display 'show'? Is 'book' the passed on variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) <%= link_to 'Show', book %>
    # => <a href="/resource/show/1">Show</a>
```

This means that `Show` is the link and path of that link is `book` to show. So if you click on `Show`, the corresponding book will be shown.

Here book has the id of 1. So you say that book with id = 1 is displayed.

Example:

```
link_to "Profile", :controller => "profiles", :action => "show", :id => @profile
# => <a href="/profiles/show/1">Profile</a>
```

Similarly,

```
link_to "Profiles", profiles_path
# => <a href="/profiles">Profiles</a>
```

The above link will have `Profiles` as link and the path to `profiles` as its path.

```
2) <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book) %></td>
            #=> <a href="/book/1/edit">Edit</a>
```

This means that `Edit` is the link and path of that link is `book` to edit. So if you click on `Edit`, the corresponding book page will be displayed for edit.

```
3) <td><%= link_to 'Remove', book, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete  %></td>
    #=> <a href=book rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Remove</a>
```

This means that `Remove` is the link and path of that link is `book` to remove. So if you click on `Remove`, the corresponding book page will be removed and will not shown in the view.

Answer (score 3):

Paths are generated by ruby's routes. You can get a list of routes available in your application by running `rake routes`, which will parse your `config/routes.rb` file and give you a list of routes and their respective paths. The output of that command should include edit_book_path, which is probably generated by a `resources :books` line in your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: Check out this Rails guide (and particularly these sections) for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects